# Does ggplot2 use/inherit some parameters in the R basic graphics?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The reason why I ask this question is that I found the `lwd` parameter is in `par()` function reference but not in `geom_boxplot()` function. We all know that the parameters in `par()` function is for R basic graphics, while `geom_boxplot()` is a ggplot2 function. But when I add a code `lwd=1.5` in the `geom_boxplot()`, the line width change 1.5 times than the default (just like the description in `par()` ). For example:

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))
p + geom_boxplot(lwd=1.5)
```

It get a plot with thicker lines:
[image]
But when I use `par(lwd=1.5)` and just use `geom_boxplot()`, nothing changed to that ggplot:

```
par(lwd = 1.5)
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))
p + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]
So I have two questions:

- Does the ggplot2 use/inherit some parameters in the R basic graphics,
  i.e parameters in `par()`?
- If it does, why I use `par(lwd = 1.5)` or something similar to
  this form can not change anything to a ggplot2 picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

‘ggplot2’ doesn’t use the settings from `par`. It also doesn’t “inherit” any parameters from base graphics. Some ‘ggplot2’ functions merely accept the base R graphics names as aliases: `lwd` works instead of `size`, and `pch` works instead of `shape`.

But I wouldn’t use those, they’re undocumented and future versions of ‘ggplot2’ might stop accepting them (admittedly unlikely). Furthermore, the aliases don’t really make sense: `geom_point(lwd = 5)` works, even though a point obviously has no “**l**ine **w**i**d**th”, so the parameter name is misleading.

Comment: Adding to this, the lookup table ggplot2 uses can be found in `ggplot2:::.base_to_ggplot`.